# Which is the most efficient way to work around the first one or the next one?

Tags: php, logic, expression

Are those expressions identical? which is more efficient?

Expression 1:

```
$a = 'default'    
if($b != "") $a = $b;
```

Expression 2:

```
$a = $b == "" ? "default" : $b;
```

Does *$a* hold the same result in both cases?

Comment: Ok! thanks for the help. I know and I did try it, I wanted to ask in case there was something i didn't think of. When one asks a question, even a simple one, the community rises with anger... this is not the spirit. If you don't want to reply with something useful, better not reply at all.

Comment: I think you need to ask a question in some another manner something like `Which is the most efficient way to work around the first one or the next one`. But in that case it suits for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depend on the situation in hand. Both are valid but for multiple scenarios this one is quicker and much more efficient

```
$a = $b == "" ? "default" : $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easily test small PHP snippets in your command line by running it interactively:

`$ php -a`

Here you can write your code:

```
$a = "test";

$b = $a;
$b = $b == "" ? "default" : $b;

var_dump($b);

$c = $a == "" ? "default" : $a;

var_dump($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same - but I would go for expression 2.
I would write it like this:

```
$this->a = ($r[0] == "") ? "default" : $r[0];
```